# Disadantages of defining inspect on BigDecimal

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bigdecimal, monkeypatching, rails-console

I am using the decimal type in Rails for storing currency.

However, I am tired of constantly seeing results like:

```
nominal_amount: #<BigDecimal:7f919884b648,'0.7E6',9(18)>
```

When I use the Rails console.

I can fix this by defining `inspect` as `def inspect; to_s; end`on `BigDecimal`, but I am concerned that it could lead to peculiar bugs.

Anyone who can vouch for or warn against this monkey patch?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ruby Doc suggests to override `inspect` for user defined classes. It returns a human readable string. No other code should rely on the functionality of `inspect`. So if you decide, that it is more human-readable - to you - if you change the default behavior it is okay. As long as you don't include it in a gem or other code foreign developers will use.

http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Object.html#method-i-inspect

Answer (score 1):

Hmm, if you put it in an initializer and run it in dev mode only... I don't see any risk. There is a chance someone else's code counts on BigDecimal.inspect returning an object string. I would say it's a development only modification.

Answer (score 1):

`inspect` "Returns *debugging* information about the value as a string".

See [apidock.com/ruby/BigDecimal/inspect](http://apidock.com/ruby/BigDecimal/inspect)

I doubt that overriding *debugging* output format can break anything. I'm monkey-patching it to `to_s` as well.